# R Loop to create Dummy Coded Field

Tags: r

I have what, to me, seems like a very complicated R Loop to perform on a set of data to determine whether or not an employee is currently termed or employed (I'm a Data Analyst who is now acting as Data Analyst and Data Scientist). To make it more complicated I would like to know whether or not they termed in a particular job code or not. I'll outline 1) what I need and 2) what would be amazing.

Sample Data:

```
    EMPLID Jobcode Job.Entry.Date  Term.Date
1   147935  100880     2016-09-04       <NA>
2   147935  100884     2015-07-27       <NA>
3   147935  100887     2013-07-28       <NA>
4   147935  100887     2013-07-28 2015-03-23
5   147935  100889     2012-12-18       <NA>
6  1510844  100890     2013-06-30       <NA>
7  1510844  100890     2013-07-21       <NA>
8  1510844  100890     2016-07-10       <NA>
9  1510844  100895     2006-01-04       <NA>
10 1510844  100895     2016-04-10       <NA>
11 1510844  100895     2016-09-04       <NA>
```

1) I want to create a new field, let's call is "TermCode" where the following is met:

> 1=The EMPLID's most recent Term.Date is after the most recent Job.Entry.Date (i.e., the EMPLID is TERMED)
>
> 0=The EMPLID's most recent Job.Entry.Date is after the most recent Term.Date (i.e., the EMPLID is NOT TERMED).

It's complicated because some EMPLID's have multiple Term.Dates and Multiple Job.Entry.Dates and they are not always on the same row.

2) The same thing as 1 except I want "TermCode" to generate the following:

> 1=The EMPLID's most recent Term.Date is after the most recent Job.Entry.Date AND is one of the following job codes (Jobcode %in% c("101545", "101318", "100897", "100895", "100891", "100885", "100884", "100880", "100879", "100875", "100873")) (i.e., the EMPLID TERMED as one of these JobCodes)
>
> 0=The EMPLID's most recent Job.Entry.Date is after the most recent Term.Date (i.e., the EMPLID is NOT TERMED)
>
> 2=The EMPLID's most recent Term.Date is after the most recent Job.Entry.Date AND is ANY other job codes (i.e., the EMPLID TERMED outside of the 11 JobCodes above)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what you are asking, but maybe this helps. I think the below code will get you the first step and you can use this logic for the second step.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(EMPLID) %>% 
  mutate(entry_date_max = max(Job.Entry.Date),
     TermCode = ifelse(!is.na(Term.Date) & Term.Date > entry_date_max, 1, 0))
```

Comment: This fascinates me, whats a good explanation of the %>%? Also is there anyway to make it produce one line per EMPLID of whatever is the highest number for that EMPLID?

Comment: Here is a good description: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html. To produce just one line switch out "mutate" for "summarise".

Comment: Great read thanks @Zak! When I replaced "mutate" with "summarise" I got an error about "expecting a single value," I assume this is because I'm using max and not sum. I attempted to use the following but no avail: jobentrydat_termcodes<-jobentrydat_alltechs %>% 
  group_by(EMPLID) %>% 
  summarise(entry_date_max = max(Job.Entry.Date),
         TermCode = unique(ifelse(!is.na(Term.Date) & Term.Date > entry_date_max, 1, 0)))